# What is the Japanese verb for vaping?

Tags: verbs, word-requests

Is there a term for vaping? The use of flavored type devices for vaping. I found the word denki tabako for the device. I was wondering what the verb would be. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98929/discussion-between-jack-and-leebo).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'To vape' is 電子タバコを吸う

The noun [電子タバコ](https://jisho.org/search/%E9%9B%BB%E5%AD%90%E3%82%BF%E3%83%90%E3%82%B3) literally means electronic cigarette and the verb [吸う](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%90%B8%E3%81%86) has many meanings aside (not just smoking), it can also mean to inhale, breathe, suck etc.

---

This Japanese game (はぁって言うゲーム) has a card that shows how versatile the 吸う verb is (funnily enough, none of which involve smoking).

[image]

Comment: @Darius, 回答欄に、是非＾＾

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Thank you, I have replaced it with the more appropriate noun

Comment: versatile word meaning